# Loop through a directory and add write a number in the pdf file

Tags: pdf, fpdi

I need to add a increasing number to all of the pdf files in directory.
I can loop through all the files.
I can write a number in one file , but when the loop starts for the next file I get an error: Cannot redeclare class PDF

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php
$PDFDIR="/home/_Facturen_PDF/";
$FTDILIB="/root/scripts/PDF/resources/FPDI";

require_once($FTDILIB.'/fpdf.php');
require_once($FTDILIB.'/fpdi.php');



if ($handle = opendir($PDFDIR)) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..','._','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4');

    while (false !== ($PDFFILE = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($PDFFILE, $blacklist)) {
            //echo $PDFFILE.PHP_EOL;
            $fullPathToFile = $PDFDIR.'/'.$PDFFILE;


class PDF extends FPDI {

    var $_tplIdx;

    function Header() {

        global $fullPathToFile;

        if (is_null($this->_tplIdx)) {

            // THIS IS WHERE YOU GET THE NUMBER OF PAGES
            $this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($fullPathToFile);
            $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);

        }
        $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx, 0, 0,200);

    }

    function Footer() {}

}

// initiate PDF
$pdf = new PDF();

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();


// The new content
$pdf->SetFont("helvetica", "B", 25);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->Text(190,10,"1");

// THIS PUTS THE REMAINDER OF THE PAGES IN
if($pdf->numPages>1) {
    for($i=2;$i<=$pdf->numPages;$i++) {
        //$pdf->endPage();
        $pdf->_tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
        $pdf->AddPage();
    }
}

//show the PDF in page
$pdf->Output($PDFDIR.'/Q1/'.$PDFFILE, 'F');


        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message: Just move the class declaration outside of your while-loop.